# WebAuthn - byte length of the "credential public key"

Tags: byte, public-key, cbor, webauthn

In WebAuthn, the authenticator data contains the variable length `attested credential data` followed by the `extensions`, if any:
[image: Authenticator data schema from the WebAuthn specification]

The `attested credential data` is made variable because of the `credential public key` field which is a CBOR map.

In case there are extensions, how to know in advance the byte length of this field, so that I can pass this field truncated **without** the extensions to a CBOR library?

The CBOR library I am using doesn't seem to handle extra bytes, and I don't know CBOR enough to know if there's a trick to compute the byte length of a map from its first bytes (or any other trick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand there is **no way to know in advance** without using a CBOR decoder (or COSE Key parser) supporting "extra bytes" first, to determine where the "credential public key data" ends and where "extension data" starts.

There is an extra note discussing exactly this in the [WebAuthn Level 2 Draft](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sec-authenticator-data).

> Determining attested credential data's length, which is variable,
>   involves determining credentialPublicKey’s beginning location given
>   the preceding credentialId’s length, and then determining the
>   credentialPublicKey’s length (see also Section 7 of [RFC8152]).

FWIW, discussed in WebAuthn spec's GitHub issue also https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1012

Comment: Hmm ok so that's by design, I guess I'll have to write another CBOR or at least COSE key parser :/
Anyway, thanks for the answer and the pointers