# WebAuthn, getting the credentialPublicKey length

Tags: webauthn

After parsing the CBOR `attestationObject`, and I'm now trying to parse the `authData`.

This contains:

https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#authenticator-data

- 32 bytes, `rpIdHash`
- 1 byte, `flags` (includes the `AT` and `ED` flags)
- 4 bytes, `signCount`
- ? bytes, `attestedCredentialData`
- ? bytes, `extensions`

Assuming the `AT` flag is true, the `attestedCredentialData` starts from byte 37, and contains:

https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-attested-credential-data

- 16 bytes, `aaguid`
- 2 bytes, `credentialIdLength` (bytes 53 - 55, seen in many implementations)
- credentialIdLength bytes, `credentialId`
- ? bytes, `credentialPublicKey`

Which means I can get the `credentialIdLength`, and extract the `credentialId`.

But how long is the `credentialPublicKey`?

I could read to the end of the end of `authData`; and that's what they show on https://webauthn.guide/ with:

```
const publicKeyBytes = authData.slice(55 + credentialIdLength);
```

But, if you look back at the authData, it could include `extensions` data after this (if the `ED` flag is true).

---

I've found the Attestation overview image quite useful for most of this:

https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-attestation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was already asked and answered: [WebAuthn - byte length of the "credential public key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045911/webauthn-byte-length-of-the-credential-public-key)

In a nutshell: you can't know the length. One way to parse it anyway is to parse a number of bytes starting from 1 (then 2, 3,... bytes) until CBOR parsing is successful.

Comment: Thanks @Tangui, I promise I did search before hand, and spent a long time reading the spec, but somehow missed this.

Comment: No problem ^^ Was at that step also just 1 year ago ;)